# IIS 7.0 Application Pool Recycling log files

Tags: iis-7, recycle

Which event log files does the IIS 7.0 Application Pool Recycling log to?
I want to check out at what time the default app pool automatically recylces.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are logged in the Windows Event Viewer. On Win7 they are in Windows Logs > System - filter for Source = WAS

A typical message may read:

> A worker process with process id of '5916' serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed.

Comment: The message above do not refer to recycle. Typical message is "A worker process with process id of 'xxxx' serving application pool 'xxxxx' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit."